# Making denylist and undenylist command using json file

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

So im trying to make a deny-list and undeny-list command using a json file so like when you type !deny-list it edits the json file and deletes the first mentions user id
I don't know how to make a command like that, I know how to add a message author_id to a json file but I don't know how to remove one so it makes the !deny-list command work

I'm new to coding and I haven't tried any code (only the deny-list but I don't know if I will be working with the !deny-list so please make both commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delete keyword.

```js
var myJson = {
"property1": true,
"property2": false
};
delete myJson['property1'];
//myJson now only has the property2 property
```

If you are using another file, remember to use fs.writeFile()!